# My App always doesn't work when I install it to C:\ProgramFiles (I Tried Both In NSIS && MSI Installers)

Tags: c#

I'm having an Issue when I install My C# winform App in C:\ProgramFiles
everytime I try to Run it, I get the usual "App has stopped working" error
with the 3 options, Close, Debug, check for online solutions.

Now I'm Pretty sure that I got all my Dlls and Requirements in the InstDir.
I'm Sure of this cuz If I copy/paste the InstDir to another location, say desktop for example, The App works !!

Why Is this happening with me ?!
am I missing any settings ?
How Can I fix this ?

ADDED:
I received This From the error message:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: typingfreak.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5029e51b
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ba1da6f
  Problem Signature 07: 3dab
  Problem Signature 08: 13c
  Problem Signature 09: System.UnauthorizedAccess
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    12297
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Please, Any Help Would Be Appreciated ..

Comment: Does your app try to create a file in the directory it's installed into, when you start it up? By default, "normal" users don't have write access under `C:\Program Files` - you'd have to write your files elsewhere....

Comment: Yes, You are right, There is a XML file in there that My app modifies every time it runs ..
can I get around this ?
like catching the exception with changing the dir access control ?
(ProgramFiles AccessControls)
Or should I just change the location of the xml, like putting it in AppData folder ?

Comment: Changing the location would probably be the easiest and most efficient way, I think you'd need admin credentials to make it work with the file under Program Files.

Comment: More specifically, the application would have to run elevated. This is a poor design - the application should consider its installation directory to be completely read-only.

Comment: @tomfanning: Mabye You're Right, But that's cuz this is the first time for me to deploy an app, I'm still a newbie, not a 10Ks Programmer ..
This Stumbling is the best way to learn, with it, I know what are the good and bad ways to do something .. 
No one can Make EVERYTHING perfect from the first Try Right ?!
That's Why I disagree with your Downvote.

Comment: Excuse you... I didn't downvote you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to retrieve an exception that is thrown in your application while it crashes. Without it it is impossible to diagnose the problem. Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event to create log and dump exception to some kind of log.